# Onclick of button works in HTML file but does not work in HTML inside a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm very new to **PHP**, **JS**, and **HTML** so I hope you don't mind if the question is very trivial. So I basically have the following code, the `onlick` would work in a separate HTML file but it will not work if I put this in an echo of a PHP file or put it in a separate html block inside a PHP file.

button.html (this works)

```
   <body>


        <p>Click the button to display the time.</p>

        <button onclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">What is the time?</button>

        <p id="demo"> </p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the echo code:

button.php (doesn't work)

```
<?php
....
....
echo "

        <input type ='button' value = 'Date'  onclick = 'getElementById('demo')=Date();' /> 

        <p id='demo'> </p>

        "
?>
```

This is the HTML code inside PHP file that doesn't work.

button.php (doesn't work)

```
<?php>

?>

<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the time.</p>

<button onclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">What is the time?</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So, why don't you show us your `echo`?

Comment: How are we supposed to tell why your code doesn't work if you only show us the code that *does* work?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.. You should check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i have tried
Hope this helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('date_time_button').innerHTML = Date()">
Click and see Date and Time.</button>

<p id="date_time_button"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code works in HTML but so is the code I wrote above. The problem is I want to run it in a PHP file, and both this and the above don't work.

Comment: I tried renaming my file to php. It worked for me! Tell me you want the button code to inside the echo tag???

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you. :) Yeah I actually want to include the html code inside the echo of php. The separate html inside php was just to test the onclick.

Comment: <?php echo '<button type="button" onclick=document.getElementById("date_time_button").innerHTML=Date();>Click and see Date and Time.</button>'; ?>

Check this.. Its working!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a single echo

```
echo ' <input type ="button" value = "Date"  onclick = "getElementById('demo')=Date();" />';
```

The single and double apostrophe sometimes are causing the error and PHP cannot understand which is what

Comment: I tried this before and it gave me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'demo' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two elements on an HTML page with same ID. Try code below.

```
<html>
  <body>
     <p>Click the button to display the time.</p>
     <button onclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">What is the time?</button>

     <p id="demo"> </p>
     <?php 
        echo ' <input type ="button" value = "Date"  onclick = getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date(); />';  
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also as mentioned by @WTFZane that The single and double apostrophe sometimes are causing the error and PHP cannot understand which is what

Comment: @Hayley works perfectly fine here. How are you implementing it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write inside a string the same quote which it's embracing the string.

You need to escape that quote with the \ character like this code:

```
echo "

        <input type ='button' value = 'Date'  onclick = \"getElementById('demo')=Date();\" /> 

        <p id='demo'> </p>

        ";
?>
```

The echo line need a ; for ending it too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Php quote Problem face here. I think you can wrong here ('demo').

```
<p id="demo"> </p> 
<button onclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">What is the time?</button>
```

Replace With this code

```
<?php echo '<p id="demo"> </p><button onclick="getElementById(\'demo\').innerHTML=Date()">What is the time?</button>';?>
```